# Set timezone on custom date/time column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I common use case (for me) when using Rails is to use custom queries, like this simplified one

```
> User.select("NOW() as now").first.now
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  NOW() as now FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => 2016-02-21 04:22:04 UTC
```

The problem here is that the timezone isn't the same as if I would just use a predefined column on the model, like `created_at`.

```
> User.first.created_at
  User Load (5.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => Wed, 20 Mar 2013 02:13:27 CET +01:00
```

Here's is another one. It's a bit more complicated example which just fetches the `created_at` coumn again, but inside a subquery.

```
user = User.select(%q{
  (
    SELECT created_at 
    FROM users u 
    WHERE u.id = users.id 
    LIMIT 1
  ) as custom_created_at, created_at
}).first

user.custom_created_at.strftime("%F %H:%M") # => "2013-03-20 01:13"
user.created_at.strftime("%F %H:%M") # => "2013-03-20 02:13"
```

I've tried setting the timezone globally, like this

```
config.time_zone = "Stockholm"
config.default_timezone = :local
```

But it only seams to apply to predefined columns, like `created_at`.

Note that I can manually set the timezone on the time object using the `Time#in_time_zone` as follows

```
> User.select("NOW() as now").first.now.in_time_zone("Stockholm")
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  NOW() as now FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => Sun, 21 Feb 2016 05:25:01 CET +01:00
```

but I don't want to do this manually to all my queries. Any idea on how to solve this?

This particular project is using Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 5 beta 2, but I would say it applies to all versions above Rails 3.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, really. You may be able to call `Time#in_time_zone` on every single Ruby Time objects, but that would do way more harm than what it can achieve. Plan B would be to set some kind of formatter for your custom queries, but that's hardly better than manually calling `Time#in_time_zone` on all custom queries.

Comment: @Harfangk It is possible. See the answer below.

Comment: But setting that config will make all your data to be saved in your local timezone too. I would prefer to keep my database in UTC to save me from other potential headaches.

Comment: @Harfangk Thanks for the info. I ended up implementing a solution of my own. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hassan's answer was temporarily working, but as @Harfangk mentioned in a comment above, this also changes all existing date columns stored in the database. This caused a lot of problems in my app, one being all pictures uploaded using paperclip stopped working (as the path is being calculated using the `created_at` column).

So I ended up writing my own concern which exposes an API that let's you define what columns that should be manually converted.

There's is an example use case.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include TimeZoneColumns
  timezone_columns :custom_created_at
end

user = User.select(%q{
  (
    SELECT created_at 
    FROM users u 
    WHERE u.id = users.id 
    LIMIT 1
  ) as custom_created_at, created_at
}).first

user.custom_created_at.strftime("%F %H:%M") # => "2013-03-20 01:13" OK
user.created_at.strftime("%F %H:%M") # => "2013-03-20 01:13" OK
```

Here's is the implementation. It uses `Time#in_time_zone` with `config.time_zone` set in your environment. I've tests that backs up the logic.

```
module TimeZoneColumns
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    # @columns A list of columns for which the timezone should be set
    def timezone_columns(*columns)
      self.columns_to_timezone = columns
    end
  end

  included do
    after_initialize :set_timezone
    class << self; attr_accessor :columns_to_timezone end
  end

  def set_timezone
    return unless whiteflagged_columns = self.class.columns_to_timezone
    is_blank = whiteflagged_columns.empty?
    attributes.each_pair do |column, value|
      if is_blank or whiteflagged_columns.include?(column.to_sym)
        if value.is_a?(Time) and not value.is_a?(ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone)
          send("#{column}=", value.in_time_zone(Rails.application.config.time_zone))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you for pointing me to your solution - it gave me much food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting

```
 config.active_record.default_timezone = 'xxxxxx'
```

in `application.rb` ?

Comment: It accepts only two values, either `:utc` or `:local`

Comment: Your solution worked at first but introduced a lot of bugs in my application. I ended up writing my own API that let's me semi-manual convert columns. Thanks for your effort tho.